# Current value of an animating property of a UWP Composition visual?

Tags: c#, animation, uwp, windows-composition-api

I have a `SpriteVisual` for which I'm animating opacity, offset, and size using `KeyFrameAnimation`s. While the animation is running the property values seem to be unaffected: they show the initial values until the animation finishes, at which point they update to the final values.

I would like to be able to get the current value part-way through the animation without having to either stop the animation to synchronise the properties or to store a separate copy of the animation and the time it started in order to calculate the value myself.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I known, it is impossible.

When we use the [`StartAnimation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Composition.CompositionObject#Windows_UI_Composition_CompositionObject_StartAnimation_System_String_Windows_UI_Composition_CompositionAnimation_) method of the [`SpriteVisual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Composition.CompositionObject) class to add the KeyFrameAnimation to it and start the animation, that there is no  method to get the current value.

We can use the `KeyFrameAnimation` and the `SpriteVisual` to change the value of the property during the animation.There is an [ForegroundFocusEffects sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/blob/831b879459e83dede4249a909612c7c2d29b3f64/SampleGallery/Samples/SDK%2014393/ForegroundFocusEffects/ForegroundFocusEffects.xaml.cs) that you can refer it, it uses the `ScalarKeyFrameAnimation` and set the `Duration` of the animation.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to understand "*there is no the process of the event*". Do you mean that there is a low-level event but the intermediate level doesn't handle it?

Comment: No, there is no event. Have you tested the sample as I said?

Comment: I haven't tested the sample because I haven't seen any reason to test it. I have working code which animates a visual, and if you're saying that what I want to do is impossible then I presume that the sample doesn't do it.